# spacemacs SPC - expand list of hints

Tags: spacemacs

I've been trying out spacemacs for a while and it looks pretty good.

I've got a problem, since I don't remember all the different commands after you press SPC, i keep having to look them up. When I do press SPC, i only get the following options.

[image]

[image: http://codingwithaxe.com/from-vim-to-emacs-with-help-of-spacemacs/]

I found the second picture from `http://codingwithaxe.com/from-vim-to-emacs-with-help-of-spacemacs/` but I'm not sure how they were able to do it.

I'm on windows8 and haven't made any changes to any configuration files.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your first screenshot in the GUI or in a terminal. What is your emacs version and OS ?

Comment: I'm using emacs 24.5 and on windows 8. It's a completely fresh windows 8 and emacs then cloned the git repository and ran it, everything updates perfectly fine and it downloads all the packages.

Comment: So i wiped emacs off my computer and tried it again.  I got the emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32.zip from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/ then git cloned using the "git clone --recursive https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d" command. Then i double clicked the runemacs.exe and updated the files and its still like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this seems to be an issue of how wide your emacs frame is and maybe how large your font is?

The problem goes away when I widen the emacs frame to around 760pixels. It turns into the three column version when you widen the frame further. [image]

Comment: Great ! You should mark this issue as resolved then.